# MySQL database normalization and best practice

Tags: php, mysql, database, normalization

I've got two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `ch_nav_items_test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `displayname` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `link` (`link`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `ch_houses_test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `displayname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `zip` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alias_link` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `alias_link` (`alias_link`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

that I want to normalize.

In ch_nav_items_test I store any navigation link the website has.
menu_id is to distinct between frontend, backend, footer ... navigation.
Parent is to build multilevel navigation. A house link would be on a second level.

When I create a new house, it'll have a display name (e.g. House Magic) and an automatically created alias (e.g. house-magic). This alias would be the link, too, with a prefix of "houses/" (e.g. houses/house-magic would be the link in ch_nav_items_test). The display name is stored in both tables atm but imho I can't use a foreign key, because the nav items table not only has house links, so there would be values that do not exist in the houses table. I am not able to build this foreign key.

What I end with is:

- ch_nav_items_test.displayname = "House Magic"
- ch_nav_itmes_test.link = "houses/house-magic"
- ch_houses_test.displayname = "House Magic"
- ch_houses_test.alias = "house-magic"
- ch_houses_test.alias-link = "houses/house-magic"

The ch_houses_test.alias-link I created temporarily to try to link to the nav link column with a foreign key without success.

It would be great to have a foreign link, because when I delete a house, I need to delete the related nav item link, too.
Also, if I change the name of the house, the link in nav items needs to be changed, too. And so the alias does.

Atm I'm stuck at how to normalize this and I don't know what is best practice here.
I'm okay with completely redefine my table structure but I want to keep it very simple.

I know that I can handle all this in php code, what I would normally do, because I'm more a php coder than a mysql expert, but if there is a simple way to handle most of this with few queries, I'd prefer this.

Comment: You need tutorials on this. Also you'll need to understand the concept of entity relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be described as an analogy in OOP. If you need several classes to have the same kind of property or behavior. What would you do? You create an interface to group these classes.

Now back to your example, the `nav_item` is the common property of `house` and other tables. What you need is a parent table or an interface that `nav_item` table can refer to. Let's call this table `links` and define it like this

```
CREATE TABLE `links` (
  `id` varchar(60) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET latin1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then the `houses` table and other tables can create their own links and refer to

```
CREATE TABLE `ch_houses_test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  `link` varchar(60) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET latin1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`link`) REFERENCES `links` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Finally, the `nav_item` can also refer to links belong to `house` or other entities

```
CREATE TABLE `ch_nav_items_test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `displayname` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`link`) REFERENCES `links` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When you want to delete or update both the house and nav_item link, simply delete or update their corresponding record in `links` table. And in case you want to extend `nav_item` to other entities just refer these entities to `links` table.

Comment: I like this idea. That means, when I create a new house, I need to create a link row first, right? Because if not, I'm not able to create the house, because there is no related foreign key with the new link name, right?

Comment: This hypothesizes, that a house link is always unique because when I need to remove a house I can't delete it by ID, I need to delete it by link in another table

Comment: Yes, that's right. Another approach is to make a parent class for `house` and other entitties. the parent class has id field that `house` can use as its id and link field to be used in `nav_item`. So you can delete the parent class using the id and `house` and `nav_item` are also deleted.